# Star Trek movie or episode containing on-screen example of replicating something else than food

Tags: star-trek, replicator

We all know that Replicators can create food items, but I'm trying to find **a screenshot or other image** that depicts someone using a replicator to create an item that is unrelated to food.

Accepted images can be from a canon source (Star Trek movie or TV episode), and must depict either the item's creation OR the item being retrieved from a replicator afterwards. Please also provide context and a source for the image.

Note that I am NOT asking about a dish, cup, bowl, or any other item that is normally used along with any food or drink. I'm asking about a weapon, a tool, a replacement part - any sort of item that you can't eat, can't drink, and don't use in the process of either eating or drinking.

Do we have any in-franchise image of anything like that being replicated? Please, only items with ***absolutely no reference to food!***.

Comment: I see, that all comments are now gone from this question, so let me explain for future readers, that this question received a lot of downvotes due to (in my opinion) big misunderstanding in nature of this question. It was later cleared by me (in some of these removed comments) and thus question recevied two good quality, nicely upvoted answers.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

### There are a considerable number of examples of replicators producing something other than food, cutlery or crockery.

In [TNG: Data's Day](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Data's_Day_(episode)), we visit the Replicator Center to see a child replicating a toy.

[image]

In [DS9: Civil Defence](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Civil_Defense_(episode)), we see the replicators generate an automated weapon.

[image]

In [TNG: Masks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Masks_(episode)), we see the replicator generate a metal mask.

[image]

In [Ent: Dead Stop](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dead_Stop_(episode)), we see a robotic arm replicate a wall panel.

[image]

In [TNG: Quality of Life](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/The_Quality_of_Life_(episode)) we learn that the *Exocomps* are able to replicate (and de-replicate) a very wide variety of complex tools from internal templates.

[image]

Comment: Apologies for the quality of the gifs. Blame the 2Mb restriction :-)

Comment: Also, didn't the exocomps use replicator-type technology to make their tools?

Comment: @imerchant - I think they had them stored in a miniature transport buffer

Comment: The Exocomps used a micro-replicator. Here's a Gif https://gifs.com/gif/tng-remastered-6x09-the-quality-of-life-comparison-sd-to-hd-oYk77j

Comment: @ench - Good point, and one that's backed up by the script. See edit...

Comment: The robotic arm with a replicator is actually really cool, too bad it's ent so it's not canon and cannot be accepted into canon.

Answer (score 13):

The entire plot of [Field of Fire (DS9)](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Field_of_Fire_%28episode%29) is about a replicated [TR-116 Rifle](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/TR-116_rifle).  If you are looking for a reference for a weapon being replicated, there you are.

> SISKO: Chief, did you ever hear of a TR one one six rifle?
>
> O'BRIEN: It was a prototype. Developed by Starfleet Security to
>   operate in energy dampening fields or radiogenic environments.
>
> SISKO: That's right. Anywhere where a normal phaser would be useless.
>   If I'm not mistaken, the TR one one six rifle fired a chemically
>   propelled tritanium bullet.
>
> ODO: You say a prototype. Were they ever
>   mass produced?
>
> O'BRIEN: No. Starfleet abandoned the TR one one six in favour of
>   regenerative phasers.
>
> SISKO: **That doesn't mean the killer couldn't have gotten hold of the
>   rifle's replication patterns.**
>
> O'BRIEN: But only Starfleet officers have access to those files.

and

> O'BRIEN: Yeah. I mean, why use a rifle if you're going to shoot
>   somebody from close range?
>
> BASHIR: I don't know. He or she may have originally intended to kill
>   their victims from a great distance, **so they replicated a long-range
>   weapon**. Or they had some special connection to this particular rifle.
>   A fetish or psychological obsession, perhaps?
>
> O'BRIEN: I suppose so.

and

> EZRI: Then why was the Security team chasing him?
>
> SISKO: Because a month ago, **he accessed the replicator patterns on
>   TR one one six without authorisation.**
>
> JORAN: Sounds guilty to me.

Every time you see replicate, or some conjugation of that, in the [script](http://www.chakoteya.net/DS9/563.htm) of this episode, it is about the weapon.

Comment: My only quibble is that you don't see it being replicated on-screen.

Comment: @Valorum This is a screen example.  'On screen' means in canon, in the material.  It does not mean "we spent special effects budget on it"

Comment: I took it to mean "*Something we actually see*" rather than "*something we hear about*" which was clearly the OP's intent. As per the OP's own comment on the [deleted answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/79933/20774) below "**This answer does not actually answers the question, so I only voted it up without accepting, since I was asking about on-screen example -- a picture from any Star Trek episode or movie.**"

Comment: @Valorum This answer predates any request for an image.  (by about 17 minutes)

Comment: I understood what he meant :-P